# Why simpledialog doesn't work with mttkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, thread-safety, simpledialog

When trying to make my simpledialog thread safe by using mttkinter, i get an error. But when using the tkinter it works perfectly. Can anyone help please.
Thanks in advance.

```
from mttkinter import mtTkinter as tk

from mttkinter import simpledialog
#### OR ####
from mtTkinter import simpledialog

#from tkinter import simpledialog


ui = tk.Tk()

input_str = tk.simpledialog.askstring("SimpleDialog", "Enter input", parent = ui)

#input_str = simpledialog.askstring("SimpleDialog", "Enter input", parent = ui)
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'simpledialog' from 'mttkinter'

Comment: try `from tkinter import simpledialog`, im not sure if `mtTkinter` has `simpledialog`

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks, yes I have already tried using `from tkinter import simpledialog` and it works perfectly

Comment: But my objective is to make my simpledialog thread safe

Comment: Then try making it work on a separate thread ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that `mtTkinter` does not have the `simpledialog` module. It [only imports the widgets in the base `Tkinter` module](https://github.com/RedFantom/mtTkinter/wiki):

> Because mtTkinter.py contains the following import from Tkinter import *, you can use every Tkinter widget and variable just as you normally would.

It's possible to make Tkinter thread safe without `mtTkinter`, and in fact there is no need to use `mtTkinter` if you are [using Python 3](https://pythonhosted.org/mttkinter/):

> mtTkinter is a thread-safe wrapper around Tkinter in Python. This module is only useful
> for Python 2.x installations, as in **Python 3 Tkinter is compiled with a flag that
> ensures thread-safety**.

If you have to use mtTkinter, try using the `Tkinter` [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) widget and making your own dialogs without `simpledialog`.

Comment: I am actually using Python 3.8, and for me it's not thread safe. Because when i tried to get the input data from my simpledialog i got an error, probably a Queue error so it was caused because i had many threads running.

Comment: As a simple solution i used another Tk Widget by making it looks as a simpledialog, but to be pro using a simpledialog will be better

Comment: Well, any problem involving tkinter and threads on Python 3.8 should be fixable. What is your error message/Queue error?

Comment: In fact it raises an exception: Exception in thread startthread:
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\...Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
.
.
.
File "C:\......Python38-32\lib\queue.py", line 147, in put
    raise Full
queue.Full

Comment: Well, I can't figure out why the exception was raised unless you can provide some example code. Maybe update your question. Are you using queues to transfer information in your program, and how?